# unique_ptr in Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, unique-ptr

I have a simple Qt project. I `include <memory>` but std::unique_ptr is not available. I know that I should use Qt specific smart pointers but I need to include a larger project that contains std::unique_ptr.

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Qt has its own  smart and shared pointers if you do not have a c++11 compiler.

Comment: What compiler are you using?  Are you using C++11/14?

Comment: How can I see that from Qt Creator?

Comment: Can you add compiler and compiler version please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 is required for smart pointers. Depending on your version of Qt:
Add `CONFIG += c++11` to your .pro file if you have *Qt5* and above. It needs to include `<memory>` as Simon mentioned.
If you have an earlier version than Qt5, try adding this:
`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11`

Answer (score 3):

Include memory:

```
#include <memory>
```

Configure your Qt project to use C++11. Add to your .pro file:

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

If that does not solve the problem, please add a detailed error message.

Comment: My .pro file looks like this: http://pastebin.com/wMKpDHAX but it does not seems to work (memory included)

Comment: How do i do this for a cmake project opened?